# How large is my team project collection's source code in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs

How would I query my database (Tfs_DefaultCollection) to have it return how much source code from a team project collection is in TFS in total? For instance, how would it return 40 GB in size?

Comment: I've never heard of storing source code in a DBMS. Do you mean code for things like stored procedures? Even then, I wouldn't store the source code in the DBMS. I would use a source code repository.

Comment: Ah, I may have not given enough information. Basically, when you set up Team Foundation Server, you create databases in SQL Server Management Studio (e.g. Tfs_DefaultCollection). I'd like to query that database.

Comment: [This should be of interest](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e5556cf-d436-4115-9c5c-b84aac6aa004/how-to-check-for-project-size)

Comment: @Russ So you've never heard of TFS? TFS is storing source code in a SQL Server database...

Comment: @Russ maybe look up TFS. What do you think any source code repository really is?

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of Team Foundation Server but didn't make the connection to TFS. Just read a bit more about it. I've used several different ones over the years, just never TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the built in SQL Server Managemnt studio reporting capability to show you the size of the tbl_Content table in your Collection database.

http://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/

Answer (score 0):

You can run this SQL query in the TFS collection database you are interested in:

```
SELECT SUM(CompressedLength) AS Size
FROM tbl_File 
WHERE OwnerId = 1 /*Version Control*/
```

It will return total size (in bytes) of the source code files in that collection.